# A producer (mapper) and consumer (reducer) problem with concurrency in go with race conditions

Tags: go, concurrency

Link to go playground https://go.dev/play/p/ctQDpDW6pui
This code has been based on suggestions and conversations in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775773/managing-producer-consumer-deadlock-in-case-of-failure)

**Architecture:**

- A read method creates a channel shared with producer. Read method adds to the channel and producer reads from it.
- A producer and consumer share a channel. Producer adds data, consumer consumes.
- The producer and consumer use error channels to communicate errors to main method.
- A hard requirement is if any worker - the producer or consumer - encounters an error then all workers should halt. This caused me to use contexts to cancel the producer and consumers.
- The producers and consumers communicate error via error channel.
- A go-routine called handleAllErrors consumes the errorChannel and uses context's cancel to call quits and shut down the remaining producers and consumers.

**Issues**

- I have tried hard to overcome challenges of deadlock and to the best of my knowledge all deadlock issues have been resolved however the code appears a some improvement.
- I am especially concerned of the race conditions of draining queues when the consumers are interrupted.
- Eg: if producers are still computing, while all the consumers get interrupted the code could blocks/deadlocks.
- Eg: if all producers are interrupted while reader is still feeding it, it may blocks.

Please review the code, help figure any deadlocks I missed and suggest a cleaner approach to some deadlocks I tried to work-around.

```
package operation

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func mapperreducer_so() {
    a1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    a2 := []int{5, 4, 3, 1, 1}
    a3 := []int{6, 7, 8, 9}
    a4 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    a5 := []int{5, 4, 3, 1, 1}
    a6 := []int{6, 7, 18, 9}
    arrayOfArray := [][]int{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    ch1 := read(ctx, arrayOfArray)

    messageCh := make(chan int)
    errCh := make(chan error)

    producerWg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        producerWg.Add(1)
        producer(ctx, producerWg, ch1, messageCh, errCh)
    }

    consumerWg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        consumerWg.Add(1)
        consumer(ctx, consumerWg, messageCh, errCh)
    }

    firstError := handleAllErrors(ctx, cancel, errCh)

    producerWg.Wait()
    close(messageCh)

    consumerWg.Wait()
    close(errCh)

    fmt.Println(<-firstError)
}

func read(ctx context.Context, arrayOfArray [][]int) <-chan []int {
    ch := make(chan []int)

    go func() {
        defer close(ch)

        for i := 0; i < len(arrayOfArray); i++ {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case ch <- arrayOfArray[i]:
            }
        }
    }()

    return ch
}

func producer(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, in <-chan []int, messageCh chan<- int, errCh chan<- error) {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case arr, ok := <-in:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }

                for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {

                    // simulating an error.
                    //if arr[i] == 10 {
                    //  errCh <- fmt.Errorf("producer interrupted")
                    //}

                    select {
                    case <-ctx.Done():
                        return
                    case messageCh <- 2 * arr[i]:
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}

func consumer(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, messageCh <-chan int, errCh chan<- error) {
    go func() {
        wg.Done()

        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case n, ok := <-messageCh:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Println("consumed: ", n)

                // simulating erros
                //if n == 10 {
                //  errCh <- fmt.Errorf("output error during write")
                //}
            }
        }
    }()
}

func handleAllErrors(ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc, errCh chan error) <-chan error {
    firstErrCh := make(chan error, 1)
    isFirstError := true
    go func() {
        defer close(firstErrCh)
        for err := range errCh {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
            default:
                cancel()
            }
            if isFirstError {
                firstErrCh <- err
                isFirstError = !isFirstError
            }
        }
    }()

    return firstErrCh
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several suggestions for you.

The first is to rename `mapperreducer_so` to `TestProducerConsumer` and to change its signature from `func()` to `func(t *testing.T)`. This will turn it into a test function that you can run with `go test`. Better still, you can give the `-race` flag to `go test` to turn on the race detector, which will tell you if there are deadlock issues in the code you test.

If you also put `TestProducerConsumer` into a file with a `_test.go` suffix, it will be omitted from any non-test build.

Next, when you create a context with `context.WithCancel`, you should immediately include a `defer cancel()` line to make sure the context is canceled no matter how you leave the function. An exception is if you want the context to persist after the function's lifetime, but that's rare and probably indicates a need to restructure your code. (If you're worried that `cancel` will be called multiple times, don't be - the second and subsequent times are harmless no-ops. The worse case is calling it zero times.)

Next, if you want an error in any goroutine to cause the other goroutines to be canceled, you want an [errgroup.Group](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group) instead of a `sync.WaitGroup`. That will obviate a lot of the logic you've written here.

Next, I suggest using a single `errgroup.Group` to contain all producers and all consumers. There doesn't seem to be any reason to prefer separate groups.

Next, it's good practice to leave it up to the caller to launch goroutines. I suggest rewriting `producer` and `consumer` to contain only the bodies of the deferred `func`s that they now contain, and changing the caller to invoke `go producer(...)` and `go consumer(...)`. (It'll look a little different if you use `errgroup.Group` as I suggested above.)

If you use `errgroup.Group`, you can and should rewrite `producer` and `consumer` to return an error instead of sending it on a channel, and that should include `ctx.Err()` in the `ctx.Done()` case.

The `wg.Done()` at the top of `consumer` should of course be `defer wg.Done()`.

Finally, permit me humbly to commend the package [github.com/bobg/go-generics/parallel](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bobg/go-generics/parallel) to your attention.